# Executor app finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143

Tags: apache-spark, hive

​Hello, I am using Hive 2.3.0 with spark version 2.0.2, When i am trying to run Hive commands on Spark from hive console,
The Job is getting stuck and i have to manually kill it.

Following was the error message in Spark worker Log. Could you please advise if i am doing something wrong.

INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20171114093447-0000/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by configuring correct EventLog directory in Spark.